# correct usage of though as conjunction

Tags: conjunctions

"Surfing is fun. It can be dangerous."

Join the above two sentences using though.

I thought of two answers

1. Though surfing is fun, it can be dangerous.
2. Surfing is fun though it can be dangerous.

Are both the answers correct?

Comment: Yes, both are correct and have the same meaning. Note that in modern grammar, concessive "though" is classified as  a preposition.

Comment: I wish I had invested in prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

You can also rewrite your second answer using appropriate punctuations in any of the following ways:

Surfing is fun, though it can be dangerous.

Surfing is fun; though, it can be dangerous.

Comment: To my understanding, if though is in the middle of sentence, it doesn't need a comma before it. Generally in basic grammar books the rule is like that. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/although-or-though

Comment: Does a comma go before though? The answer is… sometimes. Though is a versatile word in English. Read in more detail here https://proofed.com/writing-tips/should-a-comma-go-before-though/